# How to open specific path directly thru Google Photos app and setDataAndType is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, start-activity

Here is the code, which am trying to open "Camera" folder directly instead listing all the available folders.
Still it get displaying all the available folders in the device.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK); //GET INTENT also tried, still not working
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.photos");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY);
```

[image]

Comment: Intent.ACTION_PICK_FROM is not implemented i think.

Comment: Hi, @blackapps thanks for the swift reply, not getting your point, should add this this line? Intent.ACTION_PICK_FROM

Comment: The point was that what you want is not implemented i think. Why do you think it is? Show documentation please.

Comment: That is not a valid `Uri`. Also note that users do not have to have `com.google.android.apps.photos` available to them; your app will crash for those users. And note that there is no requirement that all versions of `com.google.android.apps.photos` support `ACTION_PICK`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the reply. our requirement is to open only thru Photos app. though i checked before calling the mentioned package whether the app has installed/enabled . Could you please suggest some other ways to handle this Uri, if it is wrong.

Comment: "our requirement is to open only thru Photos app" -- you are assuming that Google Photos not only supports what you are looking for, but will do so forever. I suspect that you will be disappointed in this regard. For example, there is no requirement that Google Photos pay any attention to the `Uri` that you supply. "Could you please suggest some other ways to handle this Uri" -- use a `MediaStore` `Uri`, as my guess is that is the sort of `Uri` that Google Photos might expect.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare , Yes you're right, Uri is not at all considering when using with Google Photos. just now checked .I will try with MediaStore,